# trying to match re

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to print this using regular expression

```
trying = 'Mar 20th, 2009'
```

I cant get it to print the comma after the 20th,
here is what i have tried,

```
print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[th , ]+', trying))
print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[a-z,]+', trying))
print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[a-z]+[,]', trying))
```

The desired output should be the input string.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to match? Can you post desired output too?

Comment: @GarbageCollector Posted,

Comment: Why not use an actual date parser?

Comment: im trying to find what is wrong with my code

Comment: Each of the posted lines of code print the comma for me, but not the year

Comment: Your pattern doesn't contain anything to match the year at the end of your input string, so there should be no surprise that it doesn't match it. It's a bit hard to judge what you want, since we only have one input string. The best regex pattern to match a specific string in its entirety is the string itself, but (obviously) that doesn't really generalize to other inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
>>> print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[\s]\d{1,2}th[,][\s]\d{4}',trying))
=> ['Mar 20th, 2009']`
```

And now lets see why your trials didn't give you expected result

1. `print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[th , ]+', trying))` -> This has space after `th` so it will not match
2. `print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[a-z,]+', trying))` -> by giving `+` , you search ends by finding one or more `th,` so it matches only till `th,`
3. `print (re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[\s]\d{2}[a-z]+[,]', trying))` -> similarly your searching for substring ends with `,` so macthes till `th,`

Comment: Thanks. Finally I know how to write a Python pattern equivalent to grep's `(ab|Ab)c`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression

```
r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9])[rdth]{2}, \d{4}'
```

which will match this,

```
>>> x = re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9])[rdth]{2}, \d{4}', trying)
>>> x
['Mar 20th, 2009']
>>> tryig = 'Jun 3rd, 2017'
>>> x = re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) (?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9])[rdth]{2}, \d{4}', tryig)
>>> x
['Jun 3rd, 2017']
```

**Update based on the comment:**

```
>>> regex = r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2}[rdth]{2}, \d{4}'
>>> x = re.findall(regex, trying)
>>> x
['Mar 20th, 2009']
```

Comment: You could use `\d{1,2}` instead of the non-capturing group for the date digits.